# How to get Comment and responses from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, comments

I have a two tables comments table and responses table #azure data warehouse.

Comments table

| commenid | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hi aaa |
| 2 | Hi xxx |
| 3 | Hi yyy |

Responses table

| Responseid | response | linkid | createddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | open ticket | 1 | 10-25-2021 |
| 124 | Activate | 123 ( this is my privious responseid) | 10-26-2021 |
| 3452 | Close | 124 | 10-30-2021 |
| 532 | reply to xxx | 2 | 10-25-2021 |
| 3214 | closed | 532 | 10-29-2021 |
| 654 | hold | 3 | 11-14-2021 |

Comment table and responses table has comment and first response relationship.
Responses table has first comment response  and next response.

Now i need a query which gives
My response tables with commentid  like below in Azure sql
I tried joins but not showing the below results

| Responseid | response | linkid | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | open ticket | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | Activate | 123 | 1 |
| 3452 | Close | 124 | 1 |
| 532 | reply to xxx | 2 | 2 |
| 3214 | closed | 532 | 2 |
| 654 | hold | 3 | 3 |

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please show your query

Answer (score 0):

With the following tables :

```
CREATE TABLE T_COMMENTS 
(commenid INT,  comment VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO T_COMMENTS VALUES
(1, 'Hi aaa'),
(2, 'Hi xxx'),
(3, 'Hi yyy');

CREATE TABLE T_RESPONSES
(Responseid int,    response VARCHAR(256), linkid int,  createddate DATE)
INSERT INTO T_RESPONSES VALUES
(123,  'open ticket',  1,   '10-25-2021'),
(124,  'Activate',     123, '10-26-2021'),
(3452, 'Close',        124, '10-30-2021'),
(532,  'reply to xxx', 2,   '10-25-2021'),
(3214, 'closed',       532, '10-29-2021'),
(654,  'hold',         3,   '11-14-2021');
```

The above query do the job :

```
WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT Responseid, linkid, linkid AS link_comment
FROM   T_RESPONSES 
WHERE  linkid  NOT IN (SELECT Responseid 
                       FROM   T_RESPONSES)
UNION ALL
SELECT R.Responseid, R.linkid, link_comment
FROM   T_RESPONSES AS R
       JOIN T ON T.Responseid = R.linkid
)
SELECT R.Responseid, response, R.linkid, T.link_comment, comment 
FROM   T
       JOIN T_RESPONSES AS R ON T.Responseid = R.Responseid
       JOIN T_COMMENTS AS C ON T.link_comment = C.commenid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your
Response but I'm getting error like
"Recursive common table expressions are not supposed in this version" version details: Microsoft Azure SQL Data warehouse - 10.0.13727.0.

Comment: I'm working on Azure Data warehouse, is there other way to write this logic with out recursive cte